# any way to bind parameters of embedded type in an android room database query?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

Let's say I have an entity with an embedded object:

```
public class Coordinates {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    String street;
    @Embedded
    Coordinates coordinates;
}
```

Defining a query with `longitude` and `latitude` as parameters like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Address WHERE longitude = :longitude AND latitude = :latitude")
public LiveData<List<String>> getStreet(double longitude, double latitude);
```

*works*.

But is there a way to use `Coordinates` (vs. `longitude` and `latitude`) as the query parameter? Tried this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Address WHERE longitude = :c.longitude AND latitude = :c.latitude")
public String whatStreetAt(Coordinates c);
```

but it did *not* work (getting an error in Android Studio). Any idea?

Comment: Can you try removing the `c.`?

Comment: Tried that. Does not work :-(

Comment: It seems not currently supported somehow you can just create an overloaded method that accepts `Coordinates` as argument and extract the lat and long. e.g. `public String whatStreetAt(Coordinates c){ return whatStreetAt(c.lat, c. lng); }` this also means that you need to make your DAO an abstract class.